# Is it possible to change the UUID of an Android or iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, uuid

Is it possible to change the UUID of an Android or iOS device?

Comment: What is "the UUID of an Android device"?

Comment: No, the UUID of an iOS device can't be changed.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this from a programming perspective, or from a consumer-not-wanting-to-be-tracked perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "UDID" not "UUID" then no, if you could change it that would completely defeat the purpose of having it.  Also I'm not sure Android has the same type of ID.  It probably has some unique identifier, but again being able to change it would defeat its purpose.